# Trying to delete empty rows in VBA with command button

Tags: excel, vba

i'm trying to solve a problem of mine and i'm pretty much a newbie in VBA.
I'm trying to make a quotation out of excel utilizing user form. 
Transferring data is doable from the user form, but am having some difficulty to complete the quotation:
1. Creating new empty row base on input in user form 
2. assign input to different rows and deleting any empty rows if there are no input.

This is my userform:
[image: Userform / Information input]
[image: Userform / Supply input]
[image: Quotation - to remove empty row in the middle]

```
Private Sub okaybutton_Click()

'Make quotation activate
Sheet11.Activate

'Trasnfer Information sheet
Cells(2, 6).Value = DateBox.Value
Cells(6, 2).Value = "Company: " + CompanyBox.Value
Cells(8, 2).Value = "State: " + StateBox.Value
Cells(9, 2).Value = "Name: " + PICBox.Value
Cells(10, 2).Value = "Contact Number: " + ContactCustomer.Value
Cells(7, 2).Value = "Address: " + AddressBox.Value
Cells(7, 6).Value = SEBox.Value
Cells(8, 6).Value = CNBox.Value
Cells(11, 2).Value = CusEmail.Value
Cells(9, 6).Value = ACemail.Value

If PTWrequire.Value = True Then
    Cells(13, 2).Value = "PTW application or safety induction required at site"
End If
If ESDrequire.Value = True Then
    Cells(13, 2).Value = Cells(13, 2).Value & " " & " & ESD Attire required."
End If

'SupplySide information sheet

'Determine emptyRow
nextrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B"))
nextrow1 = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B")) + 1
nextrow2 = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B")) + 2

'Dim nextrow As Long
'nextrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

'flow measurement point 1
If FlowMeasure1.Value = True Then
    Cells(nextrow, 3).Value = "Flow measurement, Measures dry air flow capacity."
    If Hottap1.Value = "Yes" Then
        Cells(nextrow, 3).Value = Cells(nextrow, 3).Value & "- perform hot tapping on " & "Main header size: " & Pipesize1.Value & """."
    Else
    Cells(nextrow, 3).Value = Cells(nextrow, 3).Value & " Main header size: " & Pipesize1.Value & """."
    End If

        If Pipesize1.Value = 2 Then
        Cells(nextrow, 4).Value = "3700"
        ElseIf Pipesize1.Value = 2.5 Then
        Cells(nextrow, 4).Value = "3706"
        ElseIf Pipesize1.Value = 3 Then
        Cells(nextrow, 4).Value = "3945"
        ElseIf Pipesize1.Value = 4 Then
        Cells(nextrow, 4).Value = "3971"
        ElseIf Pipesize1.Value = 5 Then
        Cells(nextrow, 4).Value = "3971"
        ElseIf Pipesize1.Value = 6 Then
        Cells(nextrow, 4).Value = "4080"
        End If
    If SSquantity1.Value > 0 Then
    Cells(nextrow, 2).Value = SSquantity1.Value
    End If

'flow measurement point 2

    If Hottap2.Value = "Yes" Then
        Cells(nextrow1, 3).Value = "Flow measurement, Measures dry air flow capacity." & "- perform hot tapping on " & "Main header size: " & Pipesize2.Value & """."
    ElseIf Hottap2.Value = "No" Then
    Cells(nextrow1, 3).Value = Cells(nextrow1, 3).Value & " Main header size: " & Pipesize2.Value & """."
    End If

        If Pipesize2.Value = 2 Then
        Cells(nextrow1, 4).Value = "3700"
        ElseIf Pipesize2.Value = 2.5 Then
        Cells(nextrow1, 4).Value = "3706"
        ElseIf Pipesize2.Value = 3 Then
        Cells(nextrow1, 4).Value = "3945"
        ElseIf Pipesize2.Value = 4 Then
        Cells(nextrow1, 4).Value = "3971"
        ElseIf Pipesize2.Value = 5 Then
        Cells(nextrow1, 4).Value = "3971"
        ElseIf Pipesize2.Value = 6 Then
        Cells(nextrow1, 4).Value = "4080"
        End If

    If SSquantity2.Value > 0 Then
    Cells(nextrow1, 2).Value = SSquantity2.Value
    End If

'flow measurement point 3

    If Hottap3.Value = "Yes" Then
        Cells(nextrow2, 3).Value = "Flow measurement, Measures dry air flow capacity." & "- perform hot tapping on " & "Main header size: " & Pipesize3.Value & """."
    ElseIf Hottap3.Value = "No" Then
    Cells(nextrow2, 3).Value = Cells(nextrow2, 3).Value & " Main header size: " & Pipesize3.Value & """."
    End If

        If Pipesize3.Value = 2 Then
        Cells(nextrow2, 4).Value = "3700"
        ElseIf Pipesize3.Value = 2.5 Then
        Cells(nextrow2, 4).Value = "3706"
        ElseIf Pipesize3.Value = 3 Then
        Cells(nextrow2, 4).Value = "3945"
        ElseIf Pipesize3.Value = 4 Then
        Cells(nextrow2, 4).Value = "3971"
        ElseIf Pipesize3.Value = 5 Then
        Cells(nextrow2, 4).Value = "3971"
        ElseIf Pipesize3.Value = 6 Then
        Cells(nextrow2, 4).Value = "4080"
        End If

    If SSquantity3.Value > 0 Then
    Cells(nextrow2, 2).Value = SSquantity3.Value
    End If


End If

On Error Resume Next
Worksheet.Columns("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
On Error GoTo 0


End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? Be as precise as possible please.

Comment: Much apologies.how to delete rows that are empty in a certain range on my sheet. Have input another picture onto the above.

Comment: There are many examples on this site and online generally on how to delete blank rows.

Comment: In that last bit, which should work, you have not defined `Worksheet`.

Comment: @SJR He put error handling, so everything is OK! 

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But with the code, the empty rows are still not being deleted.

Comment: @SJR Yeap there's plenty of solution here and I have tried most of them. But it can't work as well. I am placing the code at the wrong place ?

Comment: Hi guys, by using:
Sheet11.Columns("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
i get an error message: delete method of Range class failed.